# Почему массивы не дают точный результат?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть два (вроде одинаковых) алгоритма вот с этим общим блоком:

```
double U_i = 1043.928480752930;
double Am0 = 0;
double Am1 = 0;
double per_koef_usilen=48.4;
qDebug()<< "Тут расчет";
```

---

Вариант 1:

```
double Y = pow((double)10.0,(double)(per_koef_usilen/20.0));
qDebug("%.14f",Y);
Am0 = (double)(U_i/Y);
qDebug("%.14f",Am0);
 Am1 = U_i/pow(10.0,(per_koef_usilen/20.0));
 qDebug("%.14f",Am1);
```

Получаю результат `Am0 = 3.96890538899297` `Am1 = 3.96890538899297`
Их два (Am0 , Am1), чтобы проверить Y.
Но почему то если использовать массив Y, результат получается другой:

Вариант 2:

```
int K;
double *Am0 = 0;
if(Am0) delete []Am0;
Am0 = new double[obm->stor->K];
memset(Am0, 0, obm->stor->K*sizeof(double));

Am0[k] = obm->stor->U_i[k]/pow(10.0,(obm->stor->per_koef_usilen/20.0));
qDebug("%.14f",Am0[k]);
```

Результат: `Am0[1] = 3.96537540362345`. Проблема именно в том что рассходимость уже на **третьем знаке после запятой**, если хотя бы на **пятом**, то это было бы нормально, но так выглядит как будто совершенно другое число.

Моя цель понять почему `Am0` и `Am1` не равны `Am0[1]` и почему используя одни и те же переменные (отличие только в том что `Am0` это массив) я получил разный результат.

Comment: Извините, Вы не удосужитесь описать код и нужное его поведение? Трудно отвечать на вопросы вида "У меня есть код <какой-то запутанный код без пояснений>, он не работает, помогите!"

Comment: Но я описал есть первый код  " результат Am0 3.96890538899297 Am1 3.96890538899297 " и второй "печальный Am0[1] = 3.96537540362345 ." .  Am0 и  Am0[1] не сходятся хотя являются одним и тем же .

Comment: вот такой код - `double *Am0;
if(Am0) delete []Am0;` - это страшный UB. Соберите минимальный, компилируемый пример и тогда можно будет обсуждать.

Comment: че такое UB ???

Comment: UB -- Undefined Behaviour -- [Неопределённое поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В `c/с++` нужно явно инициализировать переменные, иначе у них значением может быть любым

Comment: Вам тут уже сказали про ужасные ошибки в работе с памятью. Но, все же распечатайте `obm->stor->per_koef_usilen` и `obm->stor->U_i[k]` перед вычислениями и убедитесь, что там те же числа, что и при вычислении `Am0` и `Am1`

Comment: double *Am0 = 0; поставил но результат тотже

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор вопроса (в своем ответе) написал, что ошибка у него где-то в другом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извините ребят код полностью рабочий просто у меня в коде  гдето я с OpenGL работаю вот он и режет .
а так вот код все нормально , массивы нормально работают

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
// тут библиотеки СИ языка
#include <iostream> // для оператора cout
#include <cmath> // библ отвеч за квадрат в СИ
#include <math.h> // библ отвеч за квадрат в СИ
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    double U_i = 1043.928480752930;
    double Am0 = 0;
    double Am1 = 0;
    double per_koef_usilen=48.4;
    qDebug()<< "Тут расчет";

    double Y = pow((double)10.0,(double)(per_koef_usilen/20.0));
    qDebug("%.14f",Y);
    Am0 = (double)(U_i/Y);
    qDebug("%.14f",Am0);
    Am1 = U_i/pow(10.0,(per_koef_usilen/20.0));
    qDebug("%.14f",Am1);

    int k=10;
    double *U_i_t = 0;
    if(U_i_t) delete []U_i_t;
    U_i_t = new double[k];
    memset(U_i_t, 0, k*sizeof(double));
    double *Am3 = 0;
    if(Am3) delete []Am3;
    Am3 = new double[k];
    memset(Am3, 0, k*sizeof(double));

    FILE *fid=fopen("P1Am.txt","rt");
    if(fid)
    {
        double val=0;
        for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fid,"%lf",&val);
            U_i_t[i] = val;
            qDebug("%.14f",U_i_t[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i =0; i< k; i++)
    {
        Am3[i] = U_i_t[i]/pow(10.0,(per_koef_usilen/20.0));
        qDebug("%.14f",Am3[i]);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

в файле P1Am.txt лежат 10 переменных

```
1043.928480752930
1023.487233880130
1014.657596748670
1132.028858770790
1012.557090294320
1006.203887562610
1041.219702992490
1032.005532206760
1113.350002788500
1203.141773433670
```

В общем зря я на массивы гнал .

Comment: Проверки и освобождение памяти в этих и подобных строках не нужны `double *U_i_t = 0;
    if(U_i_t) delete []U_i_t;
    U_i_t = new double[k];`. вы память еще не выделили, поэтому нечего освобождать